# How do I configure IntelliJ IDEA to use the omp4j java compiler/preprocessor?

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

I want to use the omp4j  multithreaded loop compiler/preprocessor. It is a drop in replacement for javac, which first does a source->source transform on a java file. The instructions say

"Create a shell alias for omp4j in form of java -jar "

So I made a bash script called omp4j which contains

java -jar $HOME/IdeaProjects/myproject/omp4j/omp4j-1.2.jar $@

I would like to use this command instead of the JDK javac when I build my project. How do I specify this in Intellij IDEA preferences?

Thanks

I tried the preferences menu in Intellij for build / deploy but it just lets you select which JDK to use, and it does let you specify custom args to the compiler but it doesn't seem to let you specify a custom executable name for the compiler itself